# C in Xcode cs50.h issues

Tags: c, xcode, cs50

I am trying to follow along with the cs50 course online in Xcode. I have imported the cs50 header file. I can use `printf` but I am still getting errors when calling `GetInt`. Error reads:

```
Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error "_GetInt", referenced from:
```

Any help is of course greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You're assuming people here know what "cs50" is.  Are you talking about https://cs50.harvard.edu ??  I looked there and couldn't easily find any mention of Xcode or a "header file" that I could import into some project.

Comment: Are you talking about https://manual.cs50.net/library/#_mac_os ?

Comment: Yes, I am referring to the introductory CS class at Harvard. cs50.h includes many of the functions used in the course. There is no mention of Xcode because they use Linux. Thus my challenge is following the course using a different OS and a different IDE. It's not going so well.

Comment: Exactly Arkku. I have successfully imported the header file. But Xcode will not compile even the simplest programs. i.e.:

Comment: #include "cs50.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{

    printf("Input number... \n");
    int x = GetInt();
    
    printf("You typed the number %d", x);
    
    return 0;

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `cs50.c` to your build target in XCode. To do this, select "Add files to …" from the File menu, and tick the box for all the targets. If you add more build targets, select the `cs50.c` file and in the right-side inspector pane tick the box for the new target.

Note that you can also use Terminal to use command-line as described in the course instructions. Using the example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cs50.h"
int main(void) {
    printf("Input number... \n");
    int x = GetInt();
    printf("You typed the number %d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

You can build and run it as follows (assuming the code is `foo.c` in the same directory as `cs50.h` and `cs50.c`):

```
$ clang -o foo foo.c cs50.c
$ ./foo
Input number...
5
You typed the number 5
```

Comment: When using Terminal out of the proper directory I am getting - fatal error: cs50.h not found... So now I have the .c but not the .h

Comment: Note the use of double quotes `"` in `#include "cs50.h"` - this includes the file from the current directory. To include a file from a specified include directory you would use `#include <cs50.h>`. You can add `-I.` to the compiler's command line to specify the current directory as an include directory.